# Service & Repository -> Help me to not repeat code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, service-layer

I'm creating a MVC Web App in C#, it started off with a nice-and-simple DbContext. Then I created repositories so I could write unit tests... Then I implemented dependency injection.. oh no, now I want to create a service layer between my controller and repository.

It's pretty much there apart from I don't know how to call the generic functions from my repository in the service.

Do I have to repeat all of the generic repository functions in the service?

Here's the **generic repository**:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{

    int Count { get; }

    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
      Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
      Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
      string includeProperties = "");

    IQueryable<TEntity> All();

    TEntity GetByID(object id);
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete);
    void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate);
    void Save();

}
```

**EF Repository**:

```
public abstract class Repository<CEntity, TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
                                                                    where CEntity : DbContext, new()
{
    private CEntity entities = new CEntity();
    protected CEntity context
    {
        get { return entities; }
        set { entities = value; }
    }

    public virtual int Count 
    {
        get { return entities.Set<TEntity>().Count(); }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = entities.Set<TEntity>();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> All()
    {
        return entities.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return entities.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        entities.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = entities.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            entities.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        entities.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        entities.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**Service**:

```
public class CampaignService : ICampaignService 
{
    private readonly IRepository<Campaign> _campaignRepository;

    public CampaignService(IRepository<Campaign> campaignRepository)
    {
        _campaignRepository = campaignRepository;
    }

    public Campaign GetLatestCampaign()
    {
        var query = _campaignRepository.Get(x => x.CreatedOn != null, q => q.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedOn));
        Campaign result = query.First();

        return result;
    }

}

public interface ICampaignService
{
    Campaign GetLatestCampaign();
}
```

But obviously I can't get the generic properties in the **controller**:

[image: intellisense]

Do I **have to** repeat all of the repository functions in the service? But instead of retreiving from DbContext it gets it from the repo..

Seems like a lot of repeat code, don't ya think?

Or should you repeat code but not make the service generic and specifically state what the service is doing- i.e. `_campaignService.AddCampaign(c);` instead of  `_campaignService.Add(c);`

Answer (score 2):

It's an anti-corruption layer, so yes, you would have to redefine the contract.

Think of it this way:

The generic repository interface has a job: hide any implementation details about *how* entities are persisted and retrieved.

The service interface has a job: represent use cases.

At first, it may seem like the same methods would be exposed in both cases; however, this rarely holds true except in the simplest of CRUD applications. For example, your service interface could expose multiple ways of adding a user to the system, but the implementation of those methods would simply call the lone `Insert` method in your repository interface.

Another way of thinking about this: It is incidental if your service interface looks exactly like your repository interface. You should try and shift your thinking to persistence-like language (`Insert`) or service-like language (`AddUser`) depending on what code you're working on.

Comment: Thanks, I see how in a complex system you may have different implementations of adding a user but like you say it would all boil down to a simple repository insert. So would it be better to tailor each CRUD operation on the service rather than create a generic service to perform them?

Comment: If it were up to me, then yes, that's how I'd do it. I don't want the repository abstraction to *leak* to higher-up layers like the UI. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction

Comment: However, if you anticipate that your services are nearly always or always simply calling repositories, and don't contain any business logic of any kind, you may choose to just forego the use of services altogether. You might do this if you were writing an API that was designed to perform simple CRUD operations.

Comment: @NathanAldenSr it's good practice to use both Repos and Service, even for just basic crud. Repos deal with Business (Models) and throwing exceptions, where services deal with view data (ViewModels) and model mapping. The language is also different between the two (as you described in your answer above). The only time I'll ever forgo anything is if I'm using something like NHibernate, I might forgo the Repo layer...

Answer (score 0):

We use **base repositories** and **base services** to reduce the amount of redundant code, so that our concrete implementations only have the additional methods required within them.

**Every Repository looks like this to begin with, and is extended as needed.**
*note: ModelBase is a simple base model that we use on all our models. contains things like `ID`, `LastUpdated`, `isDeleted`, etc*

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TModel> where TModel : ModelBase, new()
{
    protected RepositoryBase(UserModel loggedOnUser,
                             IDbProvider dbProvider)
    {
        DbProvider = dbProvider;
        LoggedOnUser = loggedOnUser;
    }

    public virtual Guid Create(TModel model)
    {
        // Create the record
        DbProvider.Create(model);
        return model.Id;
    }

   public virtual TModel GetById(Guid id)
    {
        var model = DbProvider.Query<TModel>(m => m.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (model == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(string.Format(NotFoundMessage, id));
        }

        return model;
    }

    public virtual IList<TModel> Find()
    {
        return DbProvider.Query<TModel>(m => m.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
    }

    public virtual void Update(TModel model)
    {
        // Set the update/create info
        SetCreateInfo(model);

        // Update the record
        try
        {
            DbProvider.Update(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ThrowKnownExceptions(ex);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TModel model)
    {
        // Do NOT SetUpdateInfo(model); it's being done in the Update method.
        model.IsDeleted = true;
        Update(model);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(Guid id)
    {
        var model = GetById(id);
        Delete(model);
    }
}
```

Then we have a generic service layer

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<TModel, TViewModel> 
    where TModel : ModelBase, new()
    where TViewModel : ViewModelBase, new()
{
    private readonly IRepository<TModel, Guid> _repository;
    protected AutoMapper<TModel> ToModel;
    protected AutoMapper<TViewModel> ToViewModel;

    protected ServiceBase(IRepository<TModel, Guid> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        ToModel = new AutoMapper<TModel>();
        ToViewModel = new AutoMapper<TViewModel>();
    }

    public virtual TViewModel Save(TViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.Id != Guid.Empty)
        {
            // The ModelObject Id is not empty, we're either updating an existing ModelObject
            // or we're inserting a new ModelObject via sync
            var model = _repository.GetById(viewModel.Id);
            if (model != null)
            {
                // Looks like we're updating a ModelObject because it's already in the database.
                _repository.Update(ToModel.BuildFrom(viewModel));
                return ToViewModel.BuildFrom(_repository.GetById(viewModel.Id));

            }
        }

        // The ModelObject is being created, either via a Sync (Guid Exists), or via an Insert (Guid doesn't Exist)
        var id = _repository.Create(ToModel.BuildFrom(viewModel));
        return ToViewModel.BuildFrom(_repository.GetById(id));
    }

    public virtual TViewModel GetById(Guid id)
    {
        var model = _repository.GetById(id);
        return ToViewModel.BuildFrom(model);
    }

    public virtual IList<TViewModel> Find()
    {
        return ToViewModel.BuildListFrom(_repository.Find());
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var model = ToModel.BuildFrom(viewModel);
        _repository.Delete(model);
    }
}
```

---

### That's it for generic stuff...##

every single repository and service will depend on the above.

any repository that is just doing basic CRUD will look like this

```
public class TenantRepository : RepositoryBase<TenantModel>, ITenantRepository
{
    public TenantRepository(UserModel loggedOnUser, IDbProvider dbProvider) : base(loggedOnUser, dbProvider)
    {
    }
}
```

And if we ever need an additional method, we just add it to the interface and the concrete implementation.  If we don't need anything beyond basic CRUD, the above Repository is "complete".

After all that, we have a similar generic service layer.

and our concrete services are as easy to implement as the concrete repositories.

**Every Service looks like this to begin with, and is extended as needed.**

```
public class TenantService : ServiceBase<TenantModel, TenantViewModel>, ITenantService
{
    private readonly ITenantRepository _TenantRepository;

    public TenantService(ITenantRepository TenantRepository)
        : base(TenantRepository)
    {
        _TenantRepository = TenantRepository;
    }
}
```

and finally, some psuedo code to show how we "find" through the service.

```
var tenantRepository = new TenantRepository(myself, mydbProvider);
var tenantService = new TenantService(tenantRepository);
var tenants = tenantService.Find();
```

That's it. Once you wire up your BaseRepository and BaseService, extending the other ones for basic CRUD require next to no redundant code.

Comment: Isn't this just addressing the repository design, though? His question was about the repository and service interface design.

Comment: I agree. This is a 'start'. Repositories deal with the business.. they throw exceptions that bubble up to the API, and they handle business `Models`. The service layer on the other hand deal with view data `ViewModels`. For us, they do the conversion using AutoMapper to map Models to ViewModels. They extend the CRUD with methods like `ChangePassword(UserModel user);`

Comment: @NathanAldenSr I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Thanks both. I will be using ViewModels along with my Services. Do you mind showing me an example of a base service? This is where I'm stuck. Would the base service be similar to the repository? And you just parse through whatever repo you require into the base service?

Comment: I've given you our exact base service above... shhhh ;)

Comment: remember, your mileage may vary, take what you need but don't just copy/paste.